# how to make a merged list of tuples

Tags: python

I have 2 lists of tuples:

```
leftlist = [(1.52, u'testSphere.vtx[299]'), (1.4450000000000001, u'testSphere.vtx[298]'), (1.0, u'testSphere.vtx[277]')   ]

rightlist = [(1.52, u'testSphere.vtx[289]'), (1.4450000000000001, u'testSphere.vtx[290]'), (1.1, u'testSphere.vtx[299]')  ]
```

I would like to extract the second element from each tuple and put into a new list of tuples, like this:

```
merged_list = [('testSphere.vtx[299]', 'testSphere.vtx[289]'), ('testSphere.vtx[298]', 'testSphere.vtx[290]'), ('testSphere.vtx[277]', 'testSphere.vtx[299]')
```

Would this best be done using a list comprehension or a for loop?

Comment: `zip([x[1] for x in leftlist], [x[1] for x in rightlist])`?

Answer (score 4):

Use zip and map/list comprehensions :

```
zip((x[1] for x in leftlist),(y[1] for y in rightlist))
zip(map(lambda x : x[1],leftlist),map(lambda y: y[1],rightlist))
```

Both will end up wih the same result

Comment: +1 for remembering to use a generator expression rather than a list comprehension

Comment: u missesd ) at end of first line

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list comprehension:

```
>>> leftlist = [(1.52, u'testSphere.vtx[299]'), (1.4450000000000001, u'testSphere.vtx[298]'), (1.0, u'testSphere.vtx[277]')   ]
>>> rightlist = [(1.52, u'testSphere.vtx[289]'), (1.4450000000000001, u'testSphere.vtx[290]'), (1.1, u'testSphere.vtx[299]')  ]
>>> result = [(x[1], y[1]) for x, y in zip(leftlist, rightlist)]
>>> result
[(u'testSphere.vtx[299]', u'testSphere.vtx[289]'), (u'testSphere.vtx[298]', u'testSphere.vtx[290]'), (u'testSphere.vtx[277]', u'testSphere.vtx[299]')]
```

Except that I notice this is the same as an answer deleted an hour ago. Give the credit to @Thrustmaster if he resurrects his answer.

---

Later:

If you want code which is faster at any cost (even if less intuitive), this is good:

```
result = [(x, y) for (_, x), (_, y) in zip(leftlist, rightlist)]
```

You can see the timing results here, if you like this kind of micro-optimization:

```
In [4]: %timeit [(leftlist[i][1],j[1]) for i,j in enumerate(rightlist)]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 680 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit [(x[1], y[1]) for x, y in zip(leftlist, rightlist)]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 787 ns per loop

In [6]: %timeit [(x, y) for (_, x), (_, y) in zip(leftlist, rightlist)]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 630 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate also which seems to be the most efficient.

```
leftlist = [(1.52, u'testSphere.vtx[299]'), (1.4450000000000001, u'testSphere.vtx[298]'), (1.0, u'testSphere.vtx[277]')   ]

rightlist = [(1.52, u'testSphere.vtx[289]'), (1.4450000000000001, u'testSphere.vtx[290]'), (1.1, u'testSphere.vtx[299]')  ]

In [12]: [(leftlist[i][1],j[1]) for i,j in enumerate(rightlist)]
Out[12]: 
[(u'testSphere.vtx[299]', u'testSphere.vtx[289]'(u'testSphere.vtx[298]',u'testSphere.vtx[290]'),(u'testSphere.vtx[277]', u'testSphere.vtx[299]')]





In [7]: %timeit [(leftlist[i][1],j[1]) for i,j in enumerate(rightlist)
]1000000 loops, best of 3: 849 ns per loop

In [8]: %timeit  [(x[1], y[1]) for x, y in zip(leftlist, rightlist)]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 951 ns per loop

In [9]: %timeit zip(map(lambda x : x[1],leftlist),map(lambda y: y[1],rightlist))
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 µs per loop

In [10]: %timeit zip((x[1] for x in leftlist),(y[1] for y in rightlist))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.11 µs per loop
```